# How to convert [{"tag":"google","count":1},{"tag":"microsoft","count":2}] to something like: {"google":1, "microsoft":2} in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to convert:

```
[
    {
        "tag":"google",
        "count":1
    },
    {
        "tag":"microsoft",
        "count":2
    }
]
```

to something like:

```
{
    "google":1,
    "microsoft":2
}
```

in *typescript* using built in function or any shortcut?

Comment: `arr.reduce((a, { tag, count }) => Object.assign(a, { [tag]: count }), {})`

Comment: Thanks I am trying it out.

Comment: What's 'a' and 'arr' here? I am new to this, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: I tried to do: ```hashtags.forEach((hashtag) => hashtagsArray.push(hashtag.tag + ':' + hashtag.count));```

Comment: But when I am simply applying the given solution, it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try `hashtags.forEach((hashtag) => hashtagsArray.push({ [hashtag.tag]:hashtag.count }));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var arr=[
    {
        "tag":"google",
        "count":1
    },
    {
        "tag":"microsoft",
        "count":2
    }
];
var k=arr.reduce((a, { tag, count }) => Object.assign(a, { [tag]: count }), {});
console.log(k);
```

[CertainPerformnce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) meant this.